# whenever I'm running my simple Selenium script its shows following errors

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

it opens the window like this

[image]

and give following error in console

```
 [6368:4624:0318/004504.962:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [00:45:04.962] Bluetooth: 
 bluetooth_adapter_winrt.cc:1072 Getting Default Adapter failed.
 [6368:10732:0318/004506.024:ERROR:data_store_impl.cc(131)] Failed to open Data Reduction Proxy DB: 3
```

here is my selenium script

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\User\Downloads\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
```

Comment: There is no error on your code please check your internet connection < are you connected with any bluetooth devices ?

Comment: I'm using inbuilt wifi

Comment: I think problem from that can you use any wifi and check this ?

Comment: yeah I'm already using wifi